# Can one exception trigger multiple catch blocks?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

I guess the easiest way to ask the question is to see if the statement "Caught Potato Except" would be printed out.

I know that "Caught Vegetable Except" would be printed out, but after that catch block will it continue sequentially and try to see if the other catch blocks would work as well?

```
class Vegetable_Except {};

class Potato_Except : public Vegetable_Except{};

int func(int n){
 if(n < 0)
  throw Potato_Except();
 cout << "n: " << n << " ";
 return func(--n);
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
 try{
  func(3);
  func(2);
 }
 catch(Vegetable_Except & e){
  cout << "Caught Vegetable Except" << endl;
 }
catch(Potato_Except & e){
cout << "Caught Potato Except" << endl;
}
 cout << "We survived the vegetables" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Code is slightly adapted from UMich F2020 EECS280.

Comment: Catch blocks should be more specific first, getting more generic as you go down, because unless you manually re-throw, then no, multiple catch blocks will not catch the exception. This is also easy enough to test out yourself, and then the question would be improved by asking how to have multiple catch blocks handle the same exception. At which point it would probably be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: TL;DR is that multiple catch blocks will only handle the same exception if they are "nested." Meaning that the code you show cannot have both catch blocks handle the same exception.